# Combining factors, represented as normal distributions, to one combined factor, normally distributed

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-normal-distribution, mixture-distribution

I'm trying to combine the different factors that may affect running pace, such as GPS-measured distance, grade, terrain, heat and other factors (such as wind etc.). Each factor is represented as a normal distribution with a mean (>1.0, unless headwind or only downhill) and variance (depending on how certain the measures are, plus considering how runners are affect to different degrees).

How would I combine all these factors to get a combined normal distribution with its own mean and variance?

In the following chart I have multiplied the mean for each factor and summarized the standard deviation for each factor. But it feels like that is not the correct, statistical method to do this and the combined curve has a variance that basically makes further calculations of predicted times have such a wide range that it's pretty useless.

[image]